# Проверка доступности файла на другом сервере

Tags: php, сервер, файлы

Файлы хранятся на другом сервере и запрашиваются на скачивание с основного.
Как правильно организовать `быструю` проверку файлов на доступность на удаленном сервере, чтобы прежде чем пользователь захочет его скачать или посмотреть описание к нему я смог проверить доступность файла и вывести сообщение.

Comment: HEAD-запрос попробуйте.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

HTTP HEAD method

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$handle = fopen('http://path-to-file', 'r');
if (false !== $handle) {
    // do something
    fclose($handle);
}
```